# Get data from datagrid C# wpf

Tags: c#, database, wpf, visual-studio

how to get data from datagrid ?

combobox xml code:

i connect combo to table MahName

`combobox1.ItemsSource = database.Mahs.ToList();`

`combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = "MahName";`

this is code datagrid

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="کد محصول" Binding="{Binding MahID}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام محصول" Binding="{Binding MahName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت فروش" Binding="{Binding MahFe}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده اول" Binding="{Binding Mah1}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده دوم" Binding="{Binding Mah2}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده سوم" Binding="{Binding Mah3}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده چهارم" Binding="{Binding Mah4}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>


        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده پنجم" Binding="{Binding Mah5}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده ششم" Binding="{Binding Mah6}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده هفتم" Binding="{Binding Mah7}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده هشتم" Binding="{Binding Mah8}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده نهم" Binding="{Binding Mah9}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام ماده دهم" Binding="{Binding Mah10}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده اول" Binding="{Binding Mahg1}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده دوم" Binding="{Binding Mahg2}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده سوم" Binding="{Binding Mahg3}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده چهارم" Binding="{Binding Mahg4}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>


        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده پنجم" Binding="{Binding Mahg5}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده ششم" Binding="{Binding Mahg6}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده هفتم" Binding="{Binding Mahg7}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده هشتم" Binding="{Binding Mahg8}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده نهم" Binding="{Binding Mahg9}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="وزن ماده دهم" Binding="{Binding Mahg10}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />



       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>






<DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده اول" Binding="{Binding Mahf1}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده دوم" Binding="{Binding Mahf2}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده سوم" Binding="{Binding Mahf3}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده چهارم" Binding="{Binding Mahf4}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده پنجم" Binding="{Binding Mahf5}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده ششم" Binding="{Binding Mahf6}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده هفتم" Binding="{Binding Mahf7}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>


        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده هشتم" Binding="{Binding Mahf8}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" قیمت ماده نهم" Binding="{Binding Mahf9}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>





        <DataGridTextColumn Header="سود" Binding="{Binding Mahd}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

i want when combobox.text = "MahName" in datagrid then "Mahg1" in datagrid /1000 then * "Mahf1" in datagrid
...

"Mahg10" in datagrid /1000 then * "Mah10" in datagrid

Mahf is price and Mahg is Weight

what should I do?

Comment: No one can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your question (I have no idea what "datagrid / 1000 then *" means). And eliminate any code that's not specifically relevant to your question.

Comment: @redcurry forget all . how can i get data from datagrid  when combobox text Equal with record of datagrid